# How to create clickable executable file that works like an .exe file on Windows?

Tags: 20.04, bash, python

I want to create a file that I can click like .exe on Windows for my python or bash script. I have also tried shc but when I click to the .x file generated it appeared a message box says

> Could Not Display *.x There is no application installed for "shared library" files. Do you want to search for an application to open this file?

I also tried to use python .pyc file but the result is the same. I also set PATH to run from terminal but whenever I run it on another folder it caused error due to the script automatically loads its modules from the folder I'm working but not from the original folder. Does anyone know how to create a file like .exe?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/script
```

Unix will only run files which have the "executable bit" set in their "mode" for the user trying to run it. `chmod` let's you change a file (or directory) mode. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions#Permissions  or for details on how to use it try `man chmod`.

For a script, it also needs to have a "[shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))" defining which script interpreter should run it.